# How to use a variable in a string concat that is defined later?

Tags: php, string

I have a variable in an array that is empty. I give it a value and echo it but it remains empty.

Here is my code:

```
$arr = array('0' => '<a href="www.example.com/vote.php?id='.$end['id'].'">');

while($end = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){

    $end['id']; // if I echo it, it will be a number, for e.g. 12

    echo $arr[0]; // output: <a href="www.example.com/vote.php?id=">
}
```

Why is the variable not replaced? How can I use `$end['id'];` in the array?

I want this output:

```
<a href="www.example.com/vote.php?id=12">
```

Comment: tldr; you cannot use a variable usefully in a string concat before it is *assigned* a value. This problem has nothing to do with the array, and might as well start off with `$result = '<a href="www.example.com/vote.php?id='.$end['id'].';` (before $end is given meaningful values) to reproduce the problem

Comment: Where is your array closing bracket `)`? You can see by the code highlighter in your question here that the code has an error.

Comment: @James sorry, that is just a typo. I will update it.

Comment: Now you're missing a closing apostrophe `'` - EDIT Ok seems ok now :) Rest of your code is highlighted correctly and not red to signify an error

Comment: @user2864740 so I can not use of a pointer ?

Comment: @Sajad There are no pointers in PHP. While there are references, these will not work with a string concat which is an *eager* evaluation operation. There are, however, ways to achieve similar end-goals. One approach is to use [`sprint`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.sprintf.php), for instance, and supply the value of $end['id'] at that time. I would recommend KISS, but I've no doubt that there are small libraries/one-off classes to achieve the goal more closely.

Comment: @user2864740 aha, too bad, anyway tnx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the solution:

```
$arr = array('0' => '<a href="www.example.com/vote.php?id=%d">');
...

echo sprintf( $arr[0],$end['id']);
```

**Output:**

```
output: <a href="www.example.com/vote.php?id=12">
```

Answer (score 0):

you can simply use this way

```
$arr = array('0' => '<a href="www.example.com/vote.php?id='".$end['id']."'">');
```

may be it will help